# Run function after any category is deleted

Tags: wordpress, hook, categories

I need to delete some of the values of custom field whenever any categories is deleted. I tried this hook but it is not working.

```
add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', function($tt_id) {

    // Whatever i need to do after a category is deleted

}, 9, 1);
```

Can any one help me with this?

EDITED:

I am dynamically populating list of categories into advanced custom field repeater which has fields like category_name, category_description, category_slug, enabled and order.

```
function my_acf_set_repeater( $value, $post_id, $field ){

//     echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';

    // this one should consists array of the names
    $settings_values = get_categories();
    
    $i = 0;

    foreach( $settings_values as $settings_value ){
//      echo $settings_value->name;
      $value[$i]['field_6357b02a9bb1b'] = $settings_value->name;
        $value[$i]['field_63594327553ef'] = $settings_value->description;
                $value[$i]['field_635945b6aa743'] = $settings_value->slug;
      $i++;

    }

//     echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
    return $value;

}

add_filter('acf/load_value/name=categories_to_display_in_homepage', 'my_acf_set_repeater', 10, 3);
```

This repeater is shown in theme option page, so that user can enable which categories to show in home page along with ordering it.

Fields like category_name, category_description, category_slug are dynamic. Fields enabled and order are custom which user fills in.
Its working fine. But the problem here is, whenever a category is deleted, it is removed from theme option page as well. But the enabled field and order field values are shifted to another category in that repeater field.

So I need to remove that field values related to deleted category as well.

Comment: Could you please a little more context, like you said, you want to delete a custom field is that related to the same term? If the term is deleted the all of its custom field will be deleted too.

Comment: [This cross-site duplicate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6218/which-are-the-hooks-run-before-after-when-a-categorys-deletion) seems to directly contradict your claim that this hook doesn't work - can you elaborate on what *specifically* you're seeing when you say "*it is not working*"? What errors are in the error log or printed to the browser, if any? Where have you dropped this code? If it's in a plugin, is the plugin activated?